# Popping balloons (Burnination request)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I propose that we Burninate the [balloon-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon-whales) tag.

As of the current posting, there is 1 question using that tag.

I think [balloon-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon-whales) is too specific a tag for WB. A combination of [flight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight) + [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design) would cover any flying animal (and thus any use of this tag), while the description for [balloon-whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon-whales) implies that it should be used literally for balloon whales.

Additionally, according to Vincent (in the comments), this tag was chosen as the chat tag specifically so that no one would ever use it, because it's so specific - now that someone is using it, the removal of the bad tag is necessary in order to guide users in the right direction towards tag usage. As of the time of this post edit, a user has already named the tag as "permissible" just because it exists, which is **wrong**.

Comment: The description appears to have been fixed to apply to any large flying creature that shouldn't normally be able to fly.

Comment: I had to look up "Burninate" (damn kids and their slang), it appears to mean destroy without reason. I think you have provided an excellent reason to Hindenburg the Balloon Whale.

Comment: To add some history. In a moment of whimsy a long time ago the worldbuilding chat got a "balloon-whales" tag (don't ask me why). Ever since then people have been talking about asking questions using that tag and wanting to create it. That's where it came from. Should it exist? Good question...

Comment: @TimB It was chosen as the chat tag specifically so that no one would ever use it, because it's so specific. But I don't know what is the purpose of having a tag for the chat in the first place.

Comment: @Vincent perhaps we should remove this tag then, since it was a chat specific tag?

Comment: @AndyD273 There's still no reason to have a specific tag for that, as the combination of flight + creature design would cover that use case.

Comment: @Samuel "Burnination" is an SO tradition, I borrowed the terminology from there

Comment: @TimB Shouldn't we try our best to guide users towards using the right tags? Having useless tags lying around is just temptation to accidentally use the wrong tag...

Comment: @Aify I'm neither supporting nor opposing the suggestion to burninate. On the one hand people wanted balloon whales. On the other hand as you correctly point out it's not the most useful tag ever. Might be worth discussing it in chat with the person who created the first question. All I'm doing is sitting on my fence dispensing information :)

Comment: The +4/-2 on this question suggests that while the tag does not have wide support neither does destroying the tag.

Comment: The post is also less than 24 hours old. Let's give some time for people to vote.

Comment: anyone more familiar with stack mechanics: won't just removing it from its one question allow it to die a natural death? (I.e. won't bots will notice it's unused and unloved and delete it automagically?) I ask because this belief is what's staying my upvote. No need to burninate if it can die a peaceful death.

Comment: @nitsua60 AFAIK, [that is exactly what happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). However, we usually wait until there are upvotes on the burnination question before we start removing the tag from all questions completely.

Comment: ah... so burnination isn't so much an overt act on the tag as it is laying waste to its expression. Gotcha. +1, then!

Comment: So going forward, with flight + creature-design, there's no need for a tag specifically for lighter-than-air, right?

Comment: @DamianYerrick Depends on your question - you may not need Creature Design, for example. But I don't think there should ever be a need for lighter-than-air as a tag, as there are enough combinations to cover everything I can think of.